# How do I create a flexbox modal that works in IE11?

Tags: css, modal-dialog, internet-explorer-11, flexbox

I've implemented this modal using flexbox because I want a sticky header and footer.  My solution works in Chrome and Firefox: http://codepen.io/cjcenizal/pen/JomaNo

Markup in Jade:

```
.blackout
  .flexModal
    .flexModal__inner
      .flexModal__header
        | Header
      .flexModal__body
        p Body content
      .flexModal__footer
        | Footer
```

SCSS:

```
.blackout {
  background-color: rgba(black, .5);
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

  .flexModal {
    max-height: calc(100% - 40px);
    min-width: 400px;
    background-color: white;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }

    .flexModal__inner {
      min-height: 100%;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
    }

    .flexModal__header {
      display: flex;
      flex-shrink: 0;
    }

    .flexModal__body {
      flex-shrink: 1;
      overflow: auto;
    }

    .flexModal__footer {
      display: flex;
      flex-shrink: 0;
    }
```

The problem is that IE11 doesn't render the modal correctly when it initially draws the page, and it doesn't re-render it correctly when enlarging the window.

Here's how it appears on first render. Notice how the footer isn't visible?

[image: Here's how it appears on first render. Notice how the footer isn't visible?]

When you make the window smaller, it re-renders correctly:
[image: When you make the window smaller, it re-renders correctly.]

When you make the window bigger, it re-renders incorrectly:
[image: When you make the window bigger, it re-renders incorrectly.]
Any suggestions about how to solve this or what the root cause is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find a solution to my technical problem, so I decided to implement my modal using the vh unit to control the size of the modal's body, the same way [this CSS modal does](http://drublic.github.io/css-modal/).

By setting `max-height: calc(100vh - {height of header + height of footer + arbitrary margin between modal and edge of browser window})` on the modal body, you can get the body to resize relative to the height of the window, which is the desired result.

Here's a codepen: http://codepen.io/cjcenizal/pen/zxMJzb